# How to iterate list in dictionary, get value from key and append to list?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Given a list of dicts where each dict have a key with a list of dict, in the following way:

```
data = [
    {
        "team": {
            "name": "Arsenal",
            "club": {
                "name": "Arsenal",
                "shortName": "Arsenal",
                "abbr": "ARS",
                "id": 1
            },
            "teamType": "FIRST",
            "shortName": "Arsenal",
            "id": 1
        },

        "players": [
            {
                "id": 4985
            },
            {

                "id": 4474
            }]}]
```

I want to create a new list of of dict where the output is a list of dicts for each player in players, but when I append `stats_temp` to `info_all` the `id` value is the same for all players for each team. How do I solve this?

Right now I get the following output from `info_all`

```
 info all = [{'id': 4985,
  'team': 'Arsenal',
  'team_id': 1,
  'team_shortName': 'Arsenal'},
{'id': 4985,
      'team': 'Arsenal',
      'team_id': 1,
      'team_shortName': 'Arsenal'}]
```

Should be:

```
info all = [{'id': 4985,
      'team': 'Arsenal',
      'team_id': 1,
      'team_shortName': 'Arsenal'},
    {'id': 4474,
          'team': 'Arsenal',
          'team_id': 1,
          'team_shortName': 'Arsenal'}]



def deep_get(dictionary, keys, default=None):
    """Get values of nested keys from dict
        Args:
            dictionary(dict): Dict with nested keys
            keys(dict.keys()): "." separated chain of nested keys, ex "info.player.name"
    """
    return reduce(lambda d, key: d.get(key, default) if isinstance(d, dict) else default, keys.split("."), dictionary)


def read_team_squads(data):
    """Read info from ...playerstats.json into flattened
    list of dicts. 
    """
    info_all = []

    for d in data:
        stats_temp = {}
        players = d['players']
        team = d['team']
        stats_temp = \
            {'team' : team['name'],
            'team_id' : deep_get(team, 'club.id'),
            'team_shortName' : deep_get(team, 'club.shortName'),}
        for player in players:
            stats_temp['id'] = player['id']
            info_all.append(stats_temp)
            print(stats_temp)

    print(info_all)
    return info_all
```

Comment: In your example you haven't defined the function `deep_get`. Please post an example which can be run without changes. Please also make it print something, specify what it prints, and specify what it should print instead.

Comment: @pts Thank you, I noticed that as well. I have updated the example with `deep get`

Comment: Maybe some dict references are shared somewhere. The code you've posted so far looks correct. Probably the bug is somewhere else in your code. Please post the shortest possible code which doesn't work correctly. Please also make it print something, specify what it prints, and specify what it should print instead.

Comment: The code you have posted so far doesn't have a `print(...)` call. Without that it's impossible to reproduce your results.

Comment: This is the shortest possible code which doesn't work correctly. The only changed thing is that I have pasted data from a json file.

Comment: Please post a single piece of code which contains a `print(...)` call, can be copy-pasted to a Python interpreter, and the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: added `print` statements, please notice that `stats_temp` have the correct output for each dict (all id's are unique) while `info_all` have the incorrect output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move `stats_temp` into the loop to avoid reference issues.

Consider the following example

```
items = []
for i in range(3):
    tmpd = {'i': i}
    for j in range(3):
        tmpd['j'] = j
        items.append(tmpd)

>>>items
[{'i': 0, 'j': 2},
 {'i': 0, 'j': 2},
 {'i': 0, 'j': 2},
 {'i': 1, 'j': 2},
 {'i': 1, 'j': 2},
 {'i': 1, 'j': 2},
 {'i': 2, 'j': 2},
 {'i': 2, 'j': 2},
 {'i': 2, 'j': 2}]
```

Compare this to

```
items = []
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        tmpd = {'i': i, 'j': j}
        items.append(tmpd)

>>>items
[{'i': 0, 'j': 0},
 {'i': 0, 'j': 1},
 {'i': 0, 'j': 2},
 {'i': 1, 'j': 0},
 {'i': 1, 'j': 1},
 {'i': 1, 'j': 2},
 {'i': 2, 'j': 0},
 {'i': 2, 'j': 1},
 {'i': 2, 'j': 2}]
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing it up, it seems so obvious now.. Thank you for taking your time to provide an illustrative example!

Answer (score 0):

The `stats_temp` dict reference is shared for all players. If you change `stats_temp['id'] = ...` for one player, the change is visible for all players, because it's the same dict object.

To solve it, copy the dict in each loop iteration:

```py
for player in players:
    stats_temp = dict(stats_temp)   # Insert this line.
```

Alternatively, you can copy like this:

```py
import copy
...
for player in players:
    stats_temp = copy.deepcopy(stats_temp)
```

Alternately, you can create a new dict in each iteration:

```
for player in players:
    stats_temp = {...}  # Creates a new dict.
```